# How to prevent Sequelize from returning model dataValues?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I was wondering if there was a way to prevent Sequelize from returning model dataValues ?

In my controller I handle POST request, here is the code :

```js
router.post("", (req, res) => {
    req.body.authorId = req.user.id;
    req.body.author = `${capitalize(req.user.lastname)} ${capitalize(req.user.firstname)}`;

    User.findByPk(req.user.id).then(user => {
        if (!user) res.status(404).statusMessage("Author of article not found");
        else {
            //let articles = user.articles;
            //let articlesArr = articles.replace(/\|/g, "").split("  ");
            let articlesArr = ["1st article", "2nd article"];
            switch (articlesArr.length) {
                case 2:
                    User.update({
                        "articles": `${articlesArr[0]} || ${articlesArr[1]}`
                    },
                    {
                        where: {
                            id: user.id
                        },
                        individualHooks: true,
                        returning: false
                    }).then(([isUpdated]) => {
                        if (!isUpdated) res.sendStatus(404);
                        else User.findByPk(user.id).then(userUpdate => res.json(userUpdate));
                    });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Whenever I use `res.json()` function, it prints also in the console the returning value :
[res.json output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgkCd.png)

I tried `logging: false` option in the sequelize config but it just disable SQL query logging. And `returning: false` did not resolved the issue.

Comment: Does it log anything if you use res.send() instead of res.json()?

Comment: Yes it still log the dataValues.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get a plain JS-object from a model instance:

```js
res.json(userUpdate.get({ plain: true }))
```